# Lamda function for tokenization

Tags: python, lambda

I am working on a project for house price prediction and one of my columns in the dataset consists of size (i.e number of bedrooms)

so when I run this `df3['size'].unique()` I get the following output

```
array(['2 BHK', '4 Bedroom', '3 BHK', '4 BHK', '6 Bedroom', '3 Bedroom',
   '1 BHK', '1 RK', '1 Bedroom', '8 Bedroom', '2 Bedroom',
   '7 Bedroom', '5 BHK', '7 BHK', '6 BHK', '5 Bedroom', '11 BHK',
   '9 BHK', '9 Bedroom', '27 BHK', '10 Bedroom', '11 Bedroom',
   '10 BHK', '19 BHK', '16 BHK', '43 Bedroom', '14 BHK', '8 BHK',
   '12 Bedroom', '13 BHK', '18 Bedroom'], dtype=object)
```

I am using the lamda function and it removes the Strings and gives only numeric values

```
df3['bhk'] = df3['size'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[0]))
df3['bhk'].unique()
```

The above code gives the output

```
array([ 2,  4,  3,  6,  1,  8,  7,  5, 11,  9, 27, 10, 19, 16, 43, 14, 12,
   13, 18], dtype=int64)
```

Can someone please explain as to how did the lambda function got executed step by step, what does that `[0]` imply in the expression

Comment: May I kindly suggest you [do the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) ?

Comment: Also [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling `apply` you are applying your lambda function to each element of your list.

With `x.split(' ')` you are splitting the strings like `'4 Bedroom'` into a list like: `['4', 'Bedroom']`

Then you take only the first element of this list `...[0]`. In this case `x.split(' ')[0] == ['4', 'Bedroom'][0] == '4'`

Later you convert this string `'4'` into an integer by calling `int(...)`

This is how you got a list of integers.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation